# JQuery Toggle .click function

Tags: onchange, jquery

I'm using jQuery Mobile. I have a toggle button that I need to launch a confirm dialog when the user clicks.

HTML

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <div class='ui-grid-a' >
        <div class='ui-block-a'>
            <h4 rel='tooltip' title='Feature that automatically solves other values as you type in inputs' style='color:#cc0000;'>Auto-Solve</h4>
        </div>
        <div class='ui-block-b'>
            <select name="togSwitch" id="autosolve" data-theme="" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
                <option value="off">Off</option>
                <option selected value="on">On</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#autosolve').toggle(function() {
    var answer = confirm('This will erase all current values. Are you sure you want to continue?');
    if (answer === false) {return;} else {reset();}
    }, function() {
    var answer = confirm('This will erase all current values. Are you sure you want to continue?');
    if (answer === false) {return;} else {reset();}
});
});
```

I've also tried to do a standard click function, but that did not work:

```
$('#autosolve').click(function() {
    var answer = confirm('This will erase all current values. Are you sure you want to continue?');
    if (answer === false) {
        return;
    } else {
        reset();
    }
});
```

I've also tried .change() but it launches onload, and it also displays a small select box underneath my toggleswitch, which is weird.

Does anyone know how to properly launch a confirm dialog once the user clicks on the toggle switch? And before the toggle changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toggle()` function used that way was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9! You should probably hook into the [built in events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/switch/events.html) for the jQ mobile toggle switch :

```
$("#autosolve").on('slidestart', function(event) {
    var answer = confirm('This will erase all current values....');
    if ( answer ) reset();
    return answer;    
});
```